# Reducing a if else if clause

Tags: java, if-statement

sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this sort of question but i am a complete newbie at java and i was wondering is there a way to make this more compact:

```
if (PlainFlourUsed <2000)   
    System.out.println("\n0 Bags of Flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 2000 && PlainFlourUsed < 4000)
    System.out.println("\n1 Bag of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 4000 && PlainFlourUsed< 6000)
    System.out.println("\n2 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 6000 && PlainFlourUsed < 8000)
    System.out.println("\n3 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 8000 && PlainFlourUsed< 10000)
    System.out.println("\n4 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 10000 && PlainFlourUsed < 12000)
    System.out.println("\n5 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 12000 && PlainFlourUsed< 14000)
    System.out.println("\n6 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 14000 && PlainFlourUsed < 16000)
    System.out.println("\n7 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 16000 && PlainFlourUsed< 18000)
    System.out.println("\n8 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 20000 && PlainFlourUsed < 22000)
    System.out.println("\n9 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 24000 && PlainFlourUsed < 26000)
    System.out.println("\n10 Bag's of flour needed");
```

*EDIT* but using that will give me a division but i can only display bags of flour such a 1 or 2. i cannot have 1.125 of a bag of flour. only whole bags of flour

Comment: The last two `if`s skip 2000. Is that a mistake?

Comment: yep im an idiot lol

Comment: The plural of bag is bags. It is never bag's.

Answer (score 17):

It's simple math:

```
int bags = PlainFlourUsed / 2000;
System.out.println("\n" + bags + " Bags of Flour needed");
```

Comment: beat me to it !

Comment: ah but using that will give me a division but i can only display bags of flour such a 1 or 2. i cannot have 1.125 of a bag of flour. only whole bags of flour

Comment: @AwaisIjaz This is integer division. You won't get any floating point numbers

Comment: @AwaisIjaz Did you try it? :)

Comment: i had to use double before so it is giving floating point numbers

Comment: yep @shmosel its giving a decimal number. i can only have a whole number, i think its because i used double for a variable previously

Comment: @AwaisIjaz That's impossible. If `PlainFlourUsed` is a `double`, you need to cast it to an `int`: `int bags = (int)PlainFlourUsed / 2000;`

Comment: but i have a variable call PlainFlour = 28.125. Then it is multiplied with the user of a scanner. Which is then the variable PlainFlourUsed

Comment: @AwaisIjaz I already explained what to do. I'm not sure what else I can add.

Comment: @shmosel sorry if im annoying you its because im a complete newbie stuck on an assignment. But i do get what you are saying thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something as simple as

```
System.out.println("\n" + (int) PlainFlourUsed/2000+" Bags of Flour needed");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compact your code and use the plural only when needed, I suggest this:

```
int n = (int) PlainFlourUsed / 2000;
System.out.println(String.format("\n%d %s of flour used", n, (n == 1 ? "bag" : "bags")));
```

Answer (score 0):

@shmosei answer is actually a very good way of doing it.

But in case you need to use all those if conditions, then you can probably remove the `>=` condition in all `else if` statements.

```
if (PlainFlourUsed <2000)   
    System.out.println("\n0 Bags of Flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 2000 && PlainFlourUsed < 4000)
    System.out.println("\n1 Bag of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 4000 && PlainFlourUsed< 6000)
    System.out.println("\n2 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed >= 6000 && PlainFlourUsed < 8000)
    System.out.println("\n3 Bag's of flour needed");
...
```

Can be changed to

```
if (PlainFlourUsed <2000)   
    System.out.println("\n0 Bags of Flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed < 4000)
    System.out.println("\n1 Bag of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed< 6000)
    System.out.println("\n2 Bag's of flour needed");
else if (PlainFlourUsed < 8000)
    System.out.println("\n3 Bag's of flour needed");
```

This is because if the value is less than 2000, it would've anyways gone inside first if condition. So no need to check for >= 2000 again in the else if.

Comment: Those apostrophes are not needed and should be worth a down vote or several

Comment: @Fogmeister The apostrophes are in the original.

Comment: @Fogmeister Since awais is new to programming, this was just a suggestion that those redundant condition in if statement can be removed. It would result in one less computation. Like I mentioned shmosei's answer was the correct one. Sometimes its good to give suggestion's to new comers, so they can apply it in future for similar cases.